# Wordpress - custom post types - not all properties being set

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a custom post type in Wordpress Developer v5.4
The custom post type is showing up in my dashboard and and I have been able to create/customize some of the attributes related to the custom post type, but not all of them seem to be getting implemented.

FUNCTION

```
{
    register_post_type('testimonials', array(
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-quote',
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Testimonials',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Testimonial',
            'new_item' => 'Add New Testimonial',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Testimonial',
            'all_items' => 'All Testimonials',
            'singular_name' => 'Testimonial'
        )
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'wrfguides_post_types');
```

For supports - excerpts and custom-fields are not showing. 
For labels, only the name is getting implemented.

Comment: do you check Screen Options (right and top of screen)? you can check boxes. I have this issue too, I hope this solution help you.

Comment: yeah, They're not even an option in the Screen Options menu. I wound up downloading the CPT UI plugin and am using that.